# Odoo12ce objet this not recognised inside of setinterval function

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, odoo-12

I working with odoo12ce and have some problems writting a new widget

My new widget shows some data and after 3 second it should disappear

```
    start: function () {
      var texto = ""
      texto += "<ul>"
      this.valor.forEach(element => {
        texto += "<li>" + element.cant + ' ' + element.type + "</li>"
      });
      texto  += "</ul>"
      this.$el.append(texto);

      setTimeout( function(){ 
        this.$el.empty();
       }, 3000);
    },
```

And I got the error: **Cannot read property 'empty' of undefined**

Outside the function the object works fine but inside it is not recognised. What could I do to solve it??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

you just need to add `this` to context of the `setTimeout`. so your code would be something like the following:

```js
start: function () {
    var self = this;
    var texto = ""
    texto += "<ul>"
    this.valor.forEach(element => {
        texto += "<li>" + element.cant + ' ' + element.type + "</li>"
    });
    texto  += "</ul>"
    this.$el.append(texto);

    setTimeout( function(){ 
       self.$el.empty();
    }, 3000);
},
```

don't hesitate to let us know if it is working or not.

Comment: Works perfect, Thanks you.